# Image not displaying in IE8

Tags: html, css

I am so confused by this little issue I am having where in IE6-8, an image logo will not display.  In Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9 and IE10 it displays as it should.  I have enclosed my code below.  I searched W3C for the CSS that I have used and as long as I specified a !DOCTYPE they should work.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="css/hmc_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="850" height="166" class="logo" />
<div class="headerImageOverlay"> <span class="spanner"> <img src="images/ross.jpg" class="overlay" /> </span> </div>
```

The CSS classes are below:

```
.container { width: 960px; background-color: #FFF; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
img.logo { z-index: 1; display: block; }
img.overlay { position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10; height: 166px; }
```

Comment: Why `img.logo` instead of just `.logo` is that class used multiple times?

Comment: @Jared that means `.logo` will be only used for `img` tag

Comment: No, it is only used once.  I have tried just .logo just in case but it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: No...I understand what it means I just didn't see anything in the html that says it's necessary.

Comment: Yes he is using for this line `<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="850" height="166" class="logo" />`

Comment: ...like I said I understand what it means...I just don't see anything that makes it necessary... aka ...I see what it matches I just don't see the point.

Comment: @Jared why it is not necessary?

Comment: @Mr.Alien because `.logo` only matches once (per Trido's comment above).  aka the `img` portion isn't necessary.  Since it does only match once it would probably be better served as an `id` instead of a `class`

Comment: @Jared why use ID unnecessarily? he is not applying any javascript to it..

Comment: Hi now define your img.overlay{width:xxxpx;} some width define in your css ....

Comment: why use a `class` unnecessarily... He's only applying it to one element.  Regardless we are starting a conversation of preference, but historically ID's are for a single element and a class is when you want to apply something to multiple elements.  With this in mind an `id` is better suited for this use.  Regardless, I'm done based on his comments this isn't relevant to his issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have told us, the most likely problem is that the image is in CMYK format which is only supported on IE9+ (*for the IE browsers*).

Convert it to RGB and it should be fine..

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know that about image mode.  The image was in CMYK and after I converted it to RGB in Photoshop, it displayed.